Cant run recovery (partitioning problems)
So I received my "new" MacBook Pro M1 Max today. I am having problems restoring the device though. Hopefully the following screenshots will explain the problem better than I can:
{From Comment by OP}
I'm trying to create a partition to install macOS on. I didn't do anything to it, it arrived in this state (bought it off ebay).
It seems it has a 5GB partition with 900GB space before it, I cant seem to expand the partition disk utility, so I need to expand the partition via terminal.
The previous owner installed Asahi Linux, and decided to remove all the partitions to reinstall macOS, ending up in this situation.


Any ideas?

What is your question?  Why are you trying to restore a new device?  Did you make a backup?  Do you mean you tried Migration Assistant?  Sorry to say but your images don’t tell us what you did or what your goal is.

I'm trying to create a partition to install macOS on. I didn't do anything to it, it arrived in this state (bought it off ebay). It seems it has a 5GB partition with 900GB space before it, I cant seem to expand the partition disk utility, so I need to expand the partition via terminal.  Edit: The previous owner installed Asahi Linux, and decided to remove all the partitions to reinstall macOS, ending up in this situation.

Would you be so kind as to include those details in the question with an [edit]?  Comments can be and often are deleted
